# Data acquisition with Python on a Beaglebone Black - Increasing sample speed

Tags: adc, python, beaglebone

This is my first foray into programming and using a BeagleBone Black. I have some limited experience in Python, and have used this within the provided Cloud9 IDE in order to capture data and write that data to a pandas dataframe, please see code below.

While the code works, I have tested using the Pins P9_32 and P9_34 with a pair of resistors to generate ~1.29 volts, then reading this voltage as an ADC input on pin P9_40. The sample rate is very slow, 113 - 116 samples per second. The minimum I need for the task I have at hand is approximately 400Hz per channel. While I can sequentially sample channels, I'd prefer to have 4 channels operational for a total of 1600Hz sample rate.

Is a significant increase in the sample rate possible by optimising or altering the Python Code I have? If not, what is the recommend method of data acquisition via the ADC on the beaglebone Black?

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ADC.setup()
value = ADC.read("P9_40")
voltage = value * 1.8 #1.8V
value2 = ADC.read_raw("P9_40")

print(voltage)
print(value2)

df_ = pd.DataFrame()

timeout_start = time.time()
timeout = 5 #seconds
print(timeout_start)

def DAQ():
    d = []
    count = 0
    while  time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
        value = ADC.read("P9_40")
        voltage = value * 1.8
        d.append((count, time.time(), voltage))
        count = count+1
        out1 = {'count': count, 'df': pd.DataFrame(d, columns=('count', 'Time', 'Signal Amplitude'))}
    return out1

x = DAQ()
count = x['count']
df = x['df']

print('end loop')
print(count, 'number of iterations', count/(time.time()-timeout_start), 'samples per second')
print(df)

print(df['Time'])
print(df['Signal Amplitude'])

#plt.plot([df['Time']],[df['Signal Amplitude']])
#plt.show()

#plt.figure()
#for count in df:
#    plt.plot(n[0], n[1], label=n[2])
#    plt.axis([0,count,0,60])
#plt.legend(loc=0, frameon=False)
```

Thank you,

P.S. if anyone can provide guidance on plotting graphs on the BBB I would appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't a clue, but I think you should add into your question your calculated acquisition time. That will determine the absolute max.

Comment: Hi Transistor, If I understand your question correctly; I've set the sample duration to 5 seconds for testing. In practice this may change depending on the sampling rate I can achieve.

Comment: No I mean how long does it take to acquire 1 ADC  conversion. E.g. 150 us.

Comment: I think you need to check the library for a way to request blocks if data.  Requesting individual values limits you to the speed of your loop - which will vary depending on what else the processor is doing.

Comment: and while you're at it: what's the final purpose of all this? I get the strong feeling that you really shouldn't be trying to sample from a software loop (much less from a software loop in a scripting language with non-deterministic garbage collection). Instead, you should probably set up the ADC to be triggered by a hardware register, transfer its readings to a memory region via DMA and then read that. *Probably* there's even a linux driver that does that for you, but I really don't know your hardware.

Comment: @Transistor - ~33000us

Comment: @chopboy 33ms ?! are you *serious*? I've yet to encounter an ADC that has a conversion time that is so HUGE.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I'm nearly certain the ADC has a sample rate of 200kHz, if not higher. The delay is almost certainly the way I'm requesting data from the ADC as JRE pointed out. I expect your thoughts above are correct, Unfortunately I'm not a programmer, so have no idea how to implement any of your suggestions above.

Comment: Not so sure if the installed operating system (non realtime) and python script is a way to do high speed real time processing.

Comment: @chopboy but Transistor asked for the *ADC conversion time*, not for your delay including software. And as I and Marco said: It's very unlikely your approach is the right one here. But again: this is all a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), because you haven't told us anything about why you want to sample what!

Comment: Thanks Marko, That's the impression I'm getting. What is the method then of getting data from the ADC? bypassing the OS entirely? Is there any way you know of to have python request a block of data from the ADC at a time as JRE implied?

Comment: @chopboy I already commented exactly on that. Please read my firstcomment.

Comment: @Marcus Müller apologies, my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Marcus Müller sorry mate, this is going over my head. Are you saying that I can trigger the ADC by a hardware register from python, direct the output somewhere specific in memory, again from python and finally read that bit of memory for the data? I have not google searched, but I don't know what your referring too RE hardware register, DMA nor how to reference a specific memory region. Thanks for your patience to date.

Comment: sorry, I was ambiguous: Usually, in such SoCs, you have *timers* that you can program to trigger the ADC, or the ADC itself has a register that you can write to that enables automatic periodic sampling. Then, the ADC typically triggers a DMA transfer (without help of the CPU) and copies its new value to some memory region. To make all this work, you'd need to a) reserve memory for that at boot time, b) assign DMA channels to that (at boot time, usually), c) have a driver in the kernel that allows you to read that memory and d) have some mechanism to let your software know there's new data.

Comment: all that is typically handled by kernel drivers, but you'll have to set up a device tree file that contains info on the things that need to be done at boot time. There's a chance your OS does have such info already, and you just need to read docs and search the web for something like "beaglebone black periodic ADC sampling"

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I'll have a web search and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Had a look at the library you are using.  It can only do single samples.  Try [this](https://bitbucket.org/intelligentagent/pypruss) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are using is not capable of doing what you want.  It can only deliver single values as fast as your loop can read them.

---

You need a different library that can access the hardware better.

The beaglebone black has what is called a programmable real-time unit (PRU.) These can be programmed to do things that need to be done quickly - like sampling the ADC at high speed.

[PyPRUSS](https://bitbucket.org/intelligentagent/pypruss) gives access to all the PRU functions with a Python API.  It may be overkill for what you need.

There's also [beaglebone_pru_adc](https://github.com/pgmmpk/beaglebone_pru_adc/blob/master/README.md) which wraps just access to the PRU ADC  functions.  It can deliver single values on request, but it also has what the developer calls "oscilloscope" mode, in which it takes a bunch of samples and delivers the them all back in one packet.

One or the other of those two ought to do the trick.

Comment: An Interim update in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution:
beaglebone_pru_adc seems to be dead as the last update was 2014, and last comments about 2016. It does not seem to function at present, as an ADC read on pin 0 influences the voltages on all downstream pins. https://github.com/pgmmpk/beaglebone_pru_adc/issues/8